# Trigger Kendo Grid saveChanges externally and get errors

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I've created a script that runs `kendoGrid.saveChanges()` on `$(document).on('submit')`. I want to  submit only when the grid(s) is able to commit the changes. How can I know if the operation was successful or not?

```
$(document).on("submit", function (e) {
    var grids = $('.k-grid');
    if (grids.length > 0)
         e.preventDefault();

    console.log(`Found ${grids.length} grids`);
    var hasErrors= false;

    $.each(grids, function () {
        var grid = $(this).data('kendoGrid');

        if (grid.dataSource.hasChanges()) {
            console.log(`Saving changes of ${$(this).attr('id')}`);

            // something like this
           if(!grid.saveChanges())
               hasError=true;              
        }
    });
     if(!hasError)
        //continue submit
});
```

Comment: You could try calling grid.dataSource.sync() directly which returns a promise.  grid.saveChanges() calls dataSource.sync() internally but does not return the promise.

Comment: thanks for pointing me to the direction!